# why does allocating memory fails even though I have enough space to allocate more?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, bad-alloc

I made a program using the SFML framework that causes memory leak out of pure curiosity (and for fun too)
this is the code:

```
int main()
{
while (m_window.isOpen())
        {
            sf::Event event;
            while (m_window.pollEvent(event))
            {
                if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed )
                    m_window.close();
                if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed)
                {
                    if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::A)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < m_dataSize; i++)
                        {
                            m_data.push_back(new sf::Int64);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Z)
                    {
                        if (m_data.size() >= m_dataSize)
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < m_dataSize; i++)
                            {
                                delete m_data.back();
                                m_data.pop_back();
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < m_data.size(); i++)
                            {
                                delete m_data.back();
                                m_data.pop_back();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            std::cout << m_data.size() << std::endl;

        }
    }
}
```

if you're not familiar with SFML (or you don't feel like going through that mess) this roughly translates to the following pseudo code:

```
int main()
{
    allocate 8 bytes of memory (multiplied by dataSize) when 
    the A button is pressed on my keyboard and push that into a vector

    deallocate 8 bytes of memory (multiplied by dataSize) when the Z button is press and pop that out of the 
    vector

    print the size of the vector

    repeat...
}
```

by observing the program in the task manager, it consumes a huge amount of memory when I hold the "A" button, until it reaches about 1,500,000 kb, at that point even though I still have around 5GB of free Ram memory, which is more than enough to allocate more, the program throw the bad_alloc exception which as far as I know (from googling that) means that there is no more free memory for me to use.

can anyone explain to me why does that happen ? why I can't allocate anymore memory despite having a lot of available space for that ?

thanks!

Comment: One possible reason is you need 1,500,000 kb of storage in one contiguous block. If your 5 GB are chopped up into scattered chunks, your memory is fragmented, finding 1.5 GB of space in one place may be difficult. This is made even harder if you're compiling for 32 bit and only have about 2.2 GB of addressing space.

Comment: @user4581301 ah I see... so there is enough memory but not enough space to allocate a contiguous chunk of memory. but I didn't use an array I used a vector? ooooh A vector uses an array to store data internally, now It makes sense. thank you

Comment: [Here's more coverage on a variety of things that can trip you up](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-nz/archive/blogs/ericlippert/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory)

Comment: you don't allocate "bits" in C++, the smallest allocatable unit is a byte. Also `new sf::Int64(200)` allocates one Int64, not 200 ints like `new sf::Int64[200]` would. Additionally ìf `0b1 << 10000000000000000000` were a number representable in C++ it would be a number with 3 quintillion decimal digits

Comment: And the smallest chunk you may be able to get from the memory manager, whatever that is on whatever system you're writing for may be significant;y larger than a single byte. Don't be overly surprised if you ask for a single `int` and find the OS gave the program a whole 4K page that it can use, abuse and subdivide if it chooses to.

Comment: @PeterT thanks for correcting me on that, I edited my post and my code to make more sense now

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < m_data.size(); i++) m_data.pop_back();` will only remove half the elements, because each loop iteration you increase `i` and reduce ` m_data.size()`

Comment: I tried the same thing but this time using a std::list instead, and I can allocate much more memory now!

Comment: Many vector implementations grow their capacity by a factor of 2 or 1.5, so adding that one more element can suddenly require you to have to allocate another huge chunk of contiguous memory. A `std::list` does not require all of its storage to be in one contiguous chunk.

Comment: @PeterT hey I don't really understand why the for loop will only remove half the elements can you please explain a bit more

Comment: @VoId I'm not Peter but here is why it would only remove half, let's use an example array `{ 0, 1, 2, 3 }`, during the first iteration of the for loop, `i = 0` and the last element will be deleted from the array, leaving you with `{ 0, 1, 2 }`, now `i = 1` and once again the last element will be deleted leaving you with `{ 0, 1 }`, now `i = 2` BUT the condition `i == m_data.size()` is true because `m_data.size()` is now 2, so the for loop stops, leaving only half the elements deleted.

Comment: @ColonD right! it makes sense now, thanks alot

Comment: @VoId -- *I still have around 5GB of free Ram memory, which is more than enough to allocate more,* -- You didn't mention if this is a 32-bit program or 64-bit program.  If it's a 32-bit program, that 5GB does you absolutely no good, as 32-bit programs cannot use that extra memory.